# Show validation error for phone number format on website page odoo 12

Tags: validation, controller, odoo, odoo-12

I'm working on sign up process for the user. Where I taking the phone from the user before sign up. And I want to show the validation when wrong phone number format.

My phone number format code in controller file is below:

```
def passwordless_signup(self, values, qcontext):
    .
    .
    .
    if values['phone']:
        phone_fields = self._get_phone_fields_to_validate()
        for phone_field in phone_fields:
            number = values['phone']
            fmt_number = request.env['res.partner'].phone_format(number)
            request.params.update({phone_field: number})
    .
    .
    .
    return request.render("auth_signup.reset_password", qcontext)
```

On Ubuntu Terminal, I'm getting below error and I want to show this as validation for user:

```
File "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/phone_validation/tools/phone_validation.py", line 25, in phone_parse
    raise UserError(_('Invalid number %s: probably incorrect prefix') % number)
odoo.exceptions.UserError: ('Invalid number 4545545: probably incorrect prefix', '')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the exception and add as `error` key with error message as the value in the `qcontext` dictionary to render that as warning provided to the frontend.

```
if values['phone']:
    phone_fields = self._get_phone_fields_to_validate()
    for phone_field in phone_fields:
        number = values['phone']
        try:
            fmt_number = request.env['res.partner'].phone_format(number)
            request.params.update({phone_field: number})
        except Exception as e:
            qcontext['error'] = str(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

in phone_validation.py add: `from odoo import exceptions` and in _get_phone_fields_to_validate method add

`if not {is_valid_phone}:
    raise exceptions.ValidationError('Invalid number %s: probably incorrect prefix' % {your_phone_value})
else:
    return {your_phone_value}`